# Python: mechanize can't find all form inputs

Tags: python, mechanize

I need to fill name="email" out, but mechanize say name="email" does not exist (look output). Why I can not find it? Do I must take an other command? Or can I solve the Problem with replace some text in the html file?

```
  <input class="box410" type="text" VCARD_NAME="vCard.Email" id="email" name="email" value="" tabindex="17" placeholder="Kontakt E-Mail Adresse" />
```

Code:

```
import mechanize

reg = "https://reg.webmail.freenet.de/freenet/Registration"
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
browser.open(reg)
browser.select_form(nr = 0)
browser.form['localpart'] = "hansp3056" #Wunschname
browser.click(type="image", nr=0) #Weiter
browser.submit().read()
browser.select_form(nr = 0)
print [form for form in browser.forms()][0]
```

Output:

```
  <regForm POST https://reg.webmail.freenet.de/freenet/Registration application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <TextControl(localpart=)>
  <RadioControl(gender=[HERR, FRAU, FIRMA])>
  <TextControl(business=)>
  <TextControl(firstname=)>
  <TextControl(lastname=)>
  <TextControl(zip=)>
  <TextControl(town=)>
  <TextControl(street=)>
  <TextControl(number=)>
  <SelectControl(bday=[*, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31])>
  <SelectControl(bmonth=[*, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12])>
  <SelectControl(byear=[*])>
  <PasswordControl(password1=)>
  <PasswordControl(password2=)>
  <TextControl(code=)>
  <HiddenControl(patrick=MjQyMDY5NC1iNDkwNzU0OThlYWE5YTM5OTgyMjk3NzA1MjQ5NzU1ZS0xMzk2NDU1NDIyLTg4ZWNjMjIzZTQzMw==) (readonly)>
  <CheckboxControl(agb=[yes])>
  <ImageControl(<None>=Senden)>
  <HiddenControl(mandant=freenet) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(action=Registration) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(JSEnabled=0) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(productID=2001004) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(startDate=2014-04-02T18:17:02+02:00) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(orderType=MAILBASIC) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(referer=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(mitarbeiter=0) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(cid=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(pwdstrength=inaktiv) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(pwdstrength2=inaktiv) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(altDomain=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(pidUrlValue=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(epidUrlValue=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(ipidUrlValue=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(pcUrlValue=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(subpcUrlValue=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(scpacoUrlValue=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(scevidUrlValue=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(ccUrlValue=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(pidCookieValue=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(epidCookieValue=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(ipidCookieValue=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(scevidCookieValue=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(scpacoCookieValue=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(subpcCookieValue=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(pcCookieValue=) (readonly)>>
```

Code:

```
browser.form["email"] = "xyz@abc.com"
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\MEGAsync_Python\Hitnews generator\email freenet.py", line 47, in <module>
    browser.form["email"] = "testmail@aol.de" #Kontaktemailadresse
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 2780, in __setitem__
control = self.find_control(name)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 3101, in find_control
return self._find_control(name, type, kind, id, label, predicate, nr)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 3185, in _find_control
raise ControlNotFoundError("no control matching "+description)
ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'email'
```

Comment: This looks like a bug, you can file it here: https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/issues

Comment: thank you! But can I not solve the problem myself?

Comment: I checked the webpage you wanted to use. You have the incorrect id in place there. It's not called email but "localpart".

Answer (score 0):

You should first select the form that you want to use and then specify the element by id. It's called `localpart` in the webpage that you have referred to. Here's the sample code:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open("https://reg.webmail.freenet.de/freenet/Registration")

# Check response here
# :
# :

form = -1
count = 0
for frm in br.forms():  
    if str(frm.attrs["id"])=="regForm":
        form = count
        break

    count += 1

# Check if form is not -1
# :
# :

br.select_form(nr=form)
```

Or, if you know that there is only one form, you could have simply done `br.select_form(nr=0)`

And then, finally:

```
br.form["localpart"] = "test@test.com"
```

Comment: Sorry I have not paste my full code. Now I have edit the Code in the first Comment.